# Q: Jekyll - 2 sections displaying nearly same content

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have two very similar sections on a jekyll website.

The displayed content change for only some words or resources.

I handle this using 3 files:

- One markdown content without Front Matter. This file content the text with `if` conditions:

```
# Mardown Content
Here is more info about: 
{% if page.section == 'sectionA' %}
[Something About Setion A](/sectionA/something)
{% elsif page.section == "sectionB" %}
[Something About Setion B](/sectionB/somethingelse)
{% endif %}
```

- Two markdown files with front matter including the content

```
---
layout: myTemplate
section: sectionA/B
title: something
---
{% include content.md %}
```

I used to have those 3 files in the same directory using `{% include_relative content.md %}`. This way seems better because the files were in the same directory and the `_include` folder do not mix up content and html templates.

But my config of jekyll builds also a page for the content file displaying an html page.

Is there a way to prevent serving this html content?

Do you know a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **_config.yml** add :

```
exclude:
 - content.md
```

This will instruct Jekyll not to process **content.md**.

Note : I don't get why you cannot put **content.md** in the **_includes** folder.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of this feature. 

I wanted to have **content**.md outside of **_includes** for consistency purpose, I thought **_include** was more about page templating. Maybe it's a misunderstanding.